# postgresql to php array with column as a index

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, indexing

not sure if this is possible, but I need to return a json object from a postgresql query

say the query returns something like this

```
who       count
=================
mary      2
had       9
a         12
lamb      9
```

the database has 2 columns "who" and "count"
i need a json object directly returned from postgresql that decodes to this

```
index   value
---------------
mary    2
had     9
a       12
lamb    9
```

so the index of the array would be from the column of "who", and the value for that array element would be from the column "count"

in other words, the column "who" would be the index for the array, and the column "count" would be the value for that

all stored in a nice little json output

im sure it can be done, and ill feel pretty stupid when someone points it out, but ive yet to figure this one out..

any ideas?

i know you can do it with a loop with php easily, but would like to just return it from the database without the messy for loop stuff

thanks

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the expected JSON structure you want.  ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: `index `is a bad name for a column. `count` is a bad name for a column. `value` is a bad name for a column. You just scored 3 out of 4.

Comment: it were a example :)

Answer (score 1):

**`jsonb_object_agg()`** will do just that:

myTable:

```
| who   | count |
| ----- | ----- |
| mary  | 2     |
| had   | 9     |
| a     | 12    |
| lamb  | 9     |


SELECT
    jsonb_object_agg(col_a, col_b) AS joa
FROM myTable;
```

This query will return a single row with the json value:

```
    {
        "a": 12,
        "had": 9,
        "lamb": 9,
        "mary": 2
    }
```

And in PHP you only need to decode it:

```
   $myTable = $PDO -> fetchColumn();
   $myTableArray = json_decode($myTable);
```

It's worth pointing out, that jsonb_object_agg() returns unique keys. So if we `INSERT INTO myTable(who, count) VALUES ('mary', 3)` the query above will still return 4 rows. Which is not bad, as you intend to use them as array keys, just keep in mind that you need to control for duplicating values in myTable.who.

Cheers!

Comment: I knew the answer would be simple...i did something similar to get it to work, but your answer is much better than I came up with, mucho thanks